# How do i create a button click event and make sure that only when i click on the button something it will do something?

Tags: android

In the MainActivity.java i changed it to:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
```

changed to abstract and added the implements OnClickListener.

Now i want to add event click for the button.
This is the button settings in the layout.

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Check Ip"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
```

I want to do that when i click the button only if i clicked on the button area not the screen then do something.

And when i finished done everything set the button to be not visible and also not clickable instead if i click now on the place where the button is it will act now like i touch the screen.

This is what i tried so far.
In the designer added a button changed the id of the button to checkforip.

Then in the MainActivity.java i did:

```
public abstract class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;
    public static MainActivity currentActivity;
    TextToSpeech mTts;
    private String targetURL;
    private String urlParameters;
    private Button btnClick;
    private String clicking = "clicked";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(new SingleTouchEventView(this, null));

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);
        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                clicking = "clicked";
            }
        });
```

First the abstract is wrong i guess also when running the program with debug mode it dosen't even pass the abstract and shut down the program.

Second i want the button click event handler to be on it's own out of the onCreate i guess.

Comment: There are a ton of tutorials online on how to make a button do something when it's clicked. If you still need help after that then I'd say post another question. It doesn't look like you've even tried writing any code.

Comment: Your question sounds like you tried to add a click listener to a button, but in the end it turned out that all screen area is clickable. If this is the case - please post the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

First get button in your Activity:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Second, listen when the button is clicked:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // add here what you want to do when button is clicked.
                } 
});
```

Third, if you want to make button disappear then add this line in `onClick`

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Answer (score 0):

First there is no need to define the class as an abstract you should remove it and remove the implementation of the listener .

Instead there is an attribute for all views in android which is onClick and you can define as follow :

```
<Button 
 ......

 android:onClick="onBtnClick"
 \>
```

After that you define a method in the java file that display this layout as follow :

```
 @override
  Public void onBtnClick (View v){
//to make it unclickable
 v.setClickable (false);
//to hide it 
 v.setVisibility (View.GONE);

 }
```